# Can't redirect using props.history.push with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, mobx

I'm actually working on my very first React app and I'm struggling with the redirect after login.

The project has been created with create-react-app v.2, I use mobx to handle the state management, and I'm trying to use react-router to navigate through the app.

Here is my code and what I have done so far :

Index.js :

```
ReactDOM.render((<Provider loginBusinessStore={new LoginBusinessStore()} > 
                        <BrowserRouter> 
                                <App /> 
                        </BrowserRouter> 
                </Provider>), document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {

    return (

      <div className="container-fluid" >

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
          <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
          <Route path='/about' component={About} />
        </Switch>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Home.js:

```
class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      < div className="bg">
      <div className="row" >
        <div className="col-sm-4"> <TextHome /> </div>
        <div className="col-sm-4"> <Login /></div>
        <div className="col-sm-4"> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

In Login.js, I'm injecting an instance of LoginBusinessStore, where I have my business logic. 
As you see when I send my credentials, it triggers the method sendCredentials of LoginBusinessStore:

```
class Login extends Component {

    onChangePassword = (event) => { this.props.loginBusinessStore.setPassword(event.target.value) }
    onChangeEmail = (event) => { this.props.loginBusinessStore.setEmail(event.target.value) };

    displayErrorMessage = () => {
        if (this.props.loginBusinessStore.loginRequestStatus == "ERROR") {
            return (<p>Oups, nous avons un problème de connexion. Rééssaie plus tard. </p>)
        } if (this.props.loginBusinessStore.loginRequestStatus == "WRONG_CREDENTIALS") {
            return (<p>La combinaison email/ mot de passe n'est pas correcte.</p>)
        } 
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="email">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" onChange={this.onChangeEmail} className="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" />
                    <small id="emailHelp" className="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" onChange={this.onChangePassword} className="form-control" id="password" />
                </div>

                <button onClick={this.props.loginBusinessStore.sendCredentials} className="btn btn-primary">Go!</button>

                <p>Créer un compte</p>
                <br />

                <div className= "error"> {this.displayErrorMessage()} </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}



export default inject("loginBusinessStore")(observer(Login));
```

```
class LoginBusinessStore {
    email;
    password;
    token = "noTokenYet";
    loginRequestStatus = "PENDING"; // "OK", "WRONG_CREDENTIALS", "ERROR"

    setToken(myToken) {
        this.token = myToken;
    };

    setEmail(myEmail) {
        this.email = myEmail;
    };

    setPassword(myPassword) {
        this.password = myPassword;
    };

    setLoginRequestStatus(myLoginRequestStatus) {
        this.loginRequestStatus = myLoginRequestStatus;
    }

    sendCredentials = () => {
        console.log("enter sendCredential");
        const axios = require("axios");
        axios.post("http://localhost:8080/authenticate/",
            { username: this.email, password: this.password }).
            then(res => {
                console.log(res.data);
                this.setToken(res.data.token);
                this.setLoginRequestStatus("OK");
                this.props.history.push("/contact");
                // window.location.replace("/contact");


            }).catch(error => {
                if (error.message.includes("401")) {
                    console.error('Combinaison email/mdp non valide', error)
                    this.setLoginRequestStatus("WRONG_CREDENTIALS");
                } else {
                    console.error('Login impossible', error)
                    this.setLoginRequestStatus("ERROR");
                }
            })
    };
}

decorate(LoginBusinessStore, {
    loginRequestStatus: observable,
    sendCredentials: action
})


export default LoginBusinessStore;
```

What I'd like to do is to redirect to a specific route if the login has been successfull. I tried with `this.props.history.push("/contact");` but get an error:

```
Cannot read property 'history' of undefined
```

If I use instead  `window.location.replace("/contact");` it does the job. But I'm not sure it's a good practice. Can someone advise me on how to handle this situation?

Comment: checkout mobx-react-router if you are using mobx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass the history props through your component tree in order to access them in `LoginBusinessStore`.

In your `Home` component you will need to pass the history props to your `Login` component:

```
<Login history={this.props.history} />
```

Then in your `Login` component, you will need to pass the history object into your `sendCredentials` function:

```
<button onClick={() => this.props.loginBusinessStore.sendCredentials(this.props.history)} className="btn btn-primary">Go!</button>
```

Lastly, in `LoginBusinessStore`, you need to adjust your function to accept the history object and use it:

```
sendCredentials = (history) => {
```

Adjust the line attempting to redirect to:

```
history.push("/contact");
```

EDIT: Updated to include the correct format for the event handler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was very helpful. Although,  passing the argument in Login as you suggested didn't work. Instead I had to write :  <button onClick={() => this.props.loginBusinessStore.sendCredentials(this.props.history)} className="btn btn-primary">Go!</button> Do you understand why is this so?

Comment: I found this on how to pass arguments in react event handlers: https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_events.asp

Comment: Last question: I'm glad it now works as expected, but could I have reached so same result more easily? I read about the "withRouter", is it something that could help in this situation?

Comment: `withRouter()` could work as well. I'm not sure if you'd be able to attach it to `LoginBusinessStore` like the other answer or if you'd need to place it in your `Login` component. I've mostly used redux for state management. Not as familiar with mobx. That being said, since your application is relatively small, using prop drilling works alright. If the app becomes larger, you might begin to consider other solutions.

Comment: And writing ```window.location.replace("/contact")``` for a redirect is a bad practice?

Comment: It is preferred that if you are using React, you should use the React Router library alongside it, as it is designed to play nicely with React.